# How to create a static web project in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to create a new **static web project** using **IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2**.
This type does not appear and I have read old questions and answers in StackOverflow but did not work with me.

I like to see the Icon of "**Static web**" project Like that :

[image]

---

Within an old question there is an answer saying that it is renamed to **JavaScript** instead of **Static web**, but for me I have the JavaScript and when click on it I cannot see the same word at the right side:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 2022.2.2, it's **New project > JavaScript**:

[image]